# Cannot get textarea value in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

Here is my plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/n8cRXwIpHJw3jUpL8PX5?p=preview You have to click on a li element and the form will appear. Enter a random string and hit 'add notice'. Instead of the textarea text you will get undefined.

Markup:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="ticket in tickets" ng-click="select(ticket)">
         {{ ticket.text }}
    </li>
</ul>
<div ui-if="selectedTicket != null">
     <form ng-submit="createNotice(selectedTicket)">
        <textarea ng-model="noticeText"></textarea>
        <button type="submit">add notice</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

JS part:

```
$scope.createNotice = function(ticket){
   alert($scope.noticeText);
}
```

returns 'undefined'. I noticed that this does not work when using ui-if of angular-ui. Any ideas why this does not work? How to fix it?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Your problem lies in the ui-if part. Angular-ui creates a new scope for anything within that directive so in order to access the parent scope, you must do something like this:

```
<textarea ng-model="$parent.noticeText"></textarea>
```

Instead of

```
<textarea ng-model="noticeText"></textarea>
```

Comment: It worked fine. Tank you so much. Can you say the reason why does it happens for textarea.

Answer (score 68):

This issue happened to me while not using the `ng-if` directive on elements surrounding the textarea element. While the solution of Mathew is correct, the reason seems to be another. Searching for that issue points to this post, so I decided to share this.

If you look at the AngularJS documentation here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/textarea , you can see that Angular adds its own directive called `<textarea>` that "overrides" the default HTML `textarea` element. This is the new scope that causes the whole mess.

If you have a variable like

```
$scope.myText = 'Dummy text';
```

in your controller and bind that to the `textarea` element like this

```
<textarea ng-model="myText"></textarea>
```

AngularJS will look for that variable in the scope of the directive. It is not there and thus he walks down to $parent. The variable is present there and the text is inserted into the `textarea`. When changing the text in the `textarea`, Angular does NOT change the parent's variable. Instead it creates a new variable in the directive's scope and thus the original variable is not updated. If you bind the `textarea` to the parent's variable, as suggested by Mathew, Angular will always bind to the correct variable and the issue is gone.

```
<textarea ng-model="$parent.myText"></textarea>
```

Hope this will clear things up for other people coming to this question and and think "WTF, I am not using ng-if or any other directive in my case!" like I did when I first landed here ;)

**Update: Use controller-as syntax**

Wanted to add this long before but didn't find time to do it. This is the modern style of building controllers and should be used instead of the `$parent` stuff above. Read on to find out *how* and *why*.

Since AngularJS 1.2 there is the ability to reference the controller object directly instead of using the `$scope` object. This may be achieved by using this syntax in HTML markup:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as myc"> [...] </div>
```

Popular routing modules (i.e. UI Router) provide similar properties for their states. For UI Router you use the following in your state definition:

```
[...]
controller: "MyController",
controllerAs: "myc",
[...]
```

This helps us to circumvent the problem with nested or incorrectly addressed scopes. The above example would be constructed this way. First the JavaScript part. Straight forward, you simple do not use the `$scope` reference to set your text, just use `this` to attach the property directly to the controller object.

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyController', function () {
    this.myText = 'Dummy text';
});
```

The markup for the `textarea` with controller-as syntax would look like this:

```
<textarea ng-model="myc.myText"></textarea>
```

This is the most efficient way to do things like this today, because it solves the problem with nested scopes making us count how many layers deep we are at a certain point. Using multiple nested directives inside elements with an `ng-controller` directive could have lead to something like this when using the old way of referencing scopes. And no one really wants to do that all day!

```
<textarea ng-model="$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.myText"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 31):

Bind the textarea to a scope variable's **property** rather than directly to a scope variable:

controller:

```
$scope.notice = {text: ""}
```

template:

```
<textarea ng-model="notice.text"></textarea>
```

Comment: This worked for me in Angular 1.5. Bizarre limitation, I'm pretty sure this used to work (back in 1.3?) bound directly to a scope variable...

Comment: This solution seems better than `$parent.notice`!!

Comment: Your solution worked. Any explanation why the direct binding failed?

Comment: This solution worked. The other solution with `$parent` did not work.

Answer (score 2):

It is, indeed, `ui-if` that creates the problem. Angular if directives destroy and recreate portions of the dom tree based on the expression. This is was creates the new scope and not the textarea directive as marandus suggested.

Here's a post on the differences between ngIf and ngShow that describes this well—[what is the difference between ng-if and ng-show/ng-hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177732/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-if-and-ng-show-ng-hide).