# How to show/hide element in ng-repeat based on value in object? Angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Ok, I'm trying to figure out how to show my various action buttons for each of my items in the list based on the value of `item.Status`. For example: I would like to only show the Edit button if `item.Status` is `'New'`. What is the best way to approach this?

Also, the solution would need to be able to support multiple values. For example, the Delete button would only show for `'New'` and `'Completed'`, but not for `'In Progress'`.

Can this be done with just ng-show?

```
<ul class="sidebar-list">
    <li class="list-item" ng-repeat="item in requestslist.value | filter:searchText | orderBy:'Modified':true">
        <div class="list-item-info">
            <ul id="" class="list-inline clearfix">
                <li class=""><span id="" class="">#{{item.Id}}</span></li>
                <li class=""><span id="" class="bold">{{item.RecipientName}}</span></li>
                <li class=""><span id="" class="">{{item.RecipientCompany}}</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="" class="list-inline clearfix">
                <li class=""><span id="" class="label label-primary">{{item.Status}}</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="list-item-actions">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button ng-click="doRemind()" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bullhorn"></span>&nbsp;Remind</button>
                <button ng-click="doView()" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>&nbsp;View</button>
                <button ng-click="doEdit(item)" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>&nbsp;Edit</button>
                <button ng-click="doClose(item)" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></span>&nbsp;Close</button>
                <button ng-click="doDelete(item)" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-minus"></span>&nbsp;Delete</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have multiple solutions :

- [`ng-show/ng-hide`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)
- [`ng-if`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

You can see the differences [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19177773/3083093).

For my the directive [`ng-if`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) is the best. Because it removed the element from the DOM.

**HTML:**

```
<button ng-if="showDelete(item.Status)">
    ...
</button>
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.showDelete = function(itemStatus) {
    var testStatus = ["New", "Completed"];

    if(testStatus.indexOf(itemStatus) > -1) { //test the Status
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

*Reference*

- [AngularJS ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)
- [AngularJS ng-show/ng-hide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)
- [MDN indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: Yea but then the deletion button would be something like this `ng-if="item.Status === 'New' || item.Status === 'Completed' || item.Status === 'In Progress'"> which is quite long.

Comment: I see why you both agree this is the best way. It is a bit cleaner and easier to maintain if the values change, vs hunting them down in the view. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: Yup and as I've said, if you think you're going to be doing this kind of checks in other parts of your app, better put the functions in a service instead of the controller, for re-usability. Ideally, controllers are just the glue between the logic in your services and your view.

Answer (score 3):

There's more than one way to do this. I personally like the declarative which means keeping your view very descriptive and free of logic. So something like this.

`<div ng-show="editingAllowed(item)">Edit</div>`

or use `ng-if`

and then in your controller

```
$scope.editingAllowed = function(item){
    //You can add aditional logic here
    if(item.status==='New'){
        return true
    }
}
```

What's nice about this is your editingAllowed function could be re-used in other directives. I'm guessing other parts of your view will depend on whether editing/deletion is allowed. You can even put that function in a service to re-use across your entire app.

Comment: This is a great answer. I was attempting this earlier, but didn't quite have the know-how. =D

Answer (score 3):

Even since it has been a while since the OP asked the question, adding my two cents in case someone else needs an easier option which is to use the [angularjs filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).

> So to show only items where `item.status === new` use:

```
 ng-repeat="item in requestslist.value | filter: {status: 'new'}
```

> IF on the other hand you want only items where `item.status !== new` use:

```
 ng-repeat="item in requestslist.value | filter: {status: '!new'}
```

Answer (score 2):

do something like

```
<button ng-show="item.Status != 'In Progress'" ng-click="doDelete(item)" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-minus"></span>&nbsp;Delete</button>
```

I haven't tested the code and this is just a suggestion.