# Angular ng-if and child element value broadcasting

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-directive

So, in two words I want to have an `input` which is placed inside of another element with [ng-if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177732/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-if-and-ng-show-ng-hide) behavior.

There is an [input focusing example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833326/how-to-set-focus-on-input-field). It works well. But until I change `ng-show` to `ng-if`.

In that case I should change my markup to the following:

```
<div data-ng-if="showPanel">
    <input type="text" data-ng-focus-on="focusInput" data-ng-model="$parent.inputValue" />
</div>
```

where ng-focus-on is my directive:

```
    // ...
    .directive('ngFocusOn', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: {
                post: function(scope, elem, attr) {
                        scope.$on(attr.ngFocusOn, function(e) {
                            window.setTimeout(function() {
                                elem[0].focus();
                            }, 0);
                        });
                    }
            }
        };
    });
```

For the focus activation I call the following from my viewmodel:

```
scope.$broadcast('focusInput');
```

... but that **does not trigger** the directive even handler **in appropriate scope**.
It does though, when I am subscribing to **parent** `scope.$parent.$on` event, but that does not make my directive universal. I would rather to call `$broadcast` relatively to appropriate scope, but that's not clear for me, which one.