# How can I unbind(remove) angular models when not in DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, unbind

Here is a simple demonstration of what I'm struggling to achieve.

```
 <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
     <input type="button" ng-click="a=!a" value="toggle a"/>
     <div ng-if="a">
         <input type="text" ng-model="del.a1" />{{del}}
     </div>
     <input type="text" ng-model="del.a2" />
     {{del}}
 </div>
```

Initially the value of del is {} and ng-if is false the property a1 is under ng-if condition.
Test Case :

step 1 : toggle the ng-if to true so that a1 is visible

step 2 : enter some value into a1 (you can anytime enter value in property a2)

step 3 : now if i again toggle ng-if to false what I'm looking for is the property a1 is to be removed from model.(i.e i just want angular to bind those models which are visible on DOM) like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/a0b70m98/)

Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/8540/) for the above test case.

I guess the problem is with model used as object. but I need a solution in model as object only as I have done lot of coding based on this.

Hope I'm clear with the question.

pls Help

Comment: Not 100% what you're asking but it seems like you can just `$watch` `a` and delete/reset the `a1` property on `del` when required. If that doesn't solve your problem then consider updating your question with more details

Comment: Hi jack watch cannot solve my problem in my application I have a object which has almost 500 to 600 properties and its dynamically assigned values so basically i just want the object to persists with those properties whose model are visible on DOM

Answer (score 0):

You can watch `a` value using `$scope.$watch` and delete a1 key from del object when a is set to false

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.del = {};
    $scope.a = false;

    $scope.$watch('a', function(value) {
        if (!value) {

            delete $scope.del['a1'];
        }

    });

})
```

#### Please see working demo below

```js
var myApp = angular.module('app', []);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.del = {};
  $scope.a = false;

  $scope.$watch('a', function(value) {
    if (!value) {

      delete $scope.del['a1'];
    }

  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="button" ng-click="a=!a" value="toggle a" />
    <div ng-if="a">
      <input type="text" ng-model="del.a1" placeholder="a1" />{{del}}</div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="del.a2 " placeholder="a2" />{{del}}
  </div>
```

Comment: since my models are dynamic and huge in size Its hard for me to delete properties one by one.

Comment: @VinodLouis in that case how do you placed 500-600 inputs on you View  page ?

Comment: I actually define an empty object like answer = {} and then run time model as answer.a answer.b and so on...

Comment: @VinodLouis so in similar way you can delete object key inside $watch function

Answer (score 0):

In your example only the models visible in the DOM are watched.

If you mean you want the model value removed from the object then you would need to have a watch on 'a' that knows what values to remove from the model.