# Conditional render in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, conditional-statements, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an Angular webApp running with Bootstrap's css.

What I'm doing now is render a table based on some data stored in a matrix, but in some cases, some rows have not relevant data to show so what I do is hide those irrelevant rows. Problem comes here: bootstrap table that I'm using adds a grey background in the pair rows and white in the odd rows.

the code in the angular template that I use is the following:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in estadisticasT1" ng-hide="row.Noches == 0 && estadisticasT2[$index].Noches == 0">                
  <directive ng-if="comparar && ((row.Noches - estadisticasT2[$index].Noches) >= 0)" class="comparativa2">+{{row.Noches - estadisticasT2[$index].Noches}}</directive>
  <directive ng-if="comparar && ((row.Noches - estadisticasT2[$index].Noches) < 0)" class="comparativa3">{{row.Noches - estadisticasT2[$index].Noches}}</directive>    
</tr>
```

I reduced the code to show only the relevant part,  tags are useles for this example, the only interesting part is that I use a ng-hide with a comparsion in order to hide the irrelevant rows of my matrix, but the problem is that in some cases it renders like this:

### [image]

As you can see the first two rows have a grey background and the next two have a white background. What I need to do is to show a grey background in the odd rows and white in the pair ones, but I can´t do this using the $index variable because it doesn't corresponds to the shown rows but all the rows being shown or not.

Any angular expert have an idea that could help me here ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Throw together a fiddle, you should probably be applying the filter on the array but it'd be easier if there was some code to work with first.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ng-hide, use ng-if. The latter removes the nodes entirely from the DOM tree, and as such, it shouldn't interfere with your parity-based CSS rules. See the details of the differences between nghide, ngshow and ng-if for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177732/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-if-and-ng-show-ng-hide), or in the angular docs themselves.

Comment: this just did the trick putting it inside the <tr> instead of the ng-hide, thanks 

ng-if="row.Noches != 0 || estadisticasT2[$index].Noches != 0"