# Render Object with optional ahref

Tags: angularjs

I have an object speaker, in my scope and I would like to render it with angularjs.

I would like to render in my html page, if speaker.url exists:

```
<a href="{{speaker.url}}">{{speaker.name}}</a>
```

Otherwise, just render (without a element):

```
{{speaker.name}}
```

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

```
<a ng-if="speaker.url" href="{{speaker.url}}">{{speaker.name}}</a>
<span ng-if="!speaker.url">{{speaker.name}}</span>
```

You can also do it using [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) with the same logic. But ng-show just shows/hides the element.  ng-if removes it from the DOM if not required.

[what is the difference between ng-if and ng-show/ng-hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177732/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-if-and-ng-show-ng-hide)