# Angularjs run directive after success of $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am making a nav using custom `directive` and when some add/remove anything from that nav I wanted to reflect changes on that nav . If that nav comes from scope then I can update scope but as nav comes from directive so I don't know how to call that directive on `$http` success.

Here is my directive :

`<nav_toolbar uuid=\"pk\" my-method=\"get_navs\"></nav_toolbar>`

Here you can see I am using some attributes too in directive which helps me to fetch exact nav options.

Directive code :

```
app.directive('synapseToolbar', function() {
   var controller = ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', '$http', '$compile','Scopes',
        function ($scope, $element, $attrs, $http, $compile, Scopes) {
        var uuid = $scope.uuid
        // my $http request comes here 
        // on $http success i'll set this below scope    
            $scope.synapse_toolbar_icons = a object
      }];
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      uuid: '=',
      method: '&myMethod',
    },
    controller: controller,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var click_fn = scope.method();
             $(element).click(function(e, rowid) {
              click_fn(scope.link_source, scope.link_fact_type);
            });
          },
    template: '<div ng-show="synapse_toolbar_icons" ng-repeat="toolbar in synapse_toolbar_icons" class="tile iconSizeClass synapse-toolbar bg-crimson ng-scope" data-toggle="tooltip" ng-click="bindData(toolbar.link_source, toolbar.link_fact_type)">'+
              '<div dynamic="toolbar.icon_html"></div>'+
              '</div>',
  };
});
```

**Function on which I want to call directive again**

```
$scope.remove_synapse_link = function(){

        $http({
                method : 'POST',
            }).success(function(data,status){
                // here I want to call that directive again 
            })
            .error(function(data,status){
                    $.notify("Something went wrong while adding dislike", "error");
            }); 
    }
```

**Plunker** http://plnkr.co/edit/FpzGkIpBPfOnoFrwQkmj?p=preview

Comment: I think you need to use a $watch function.  Can you please provide the directive and controller code?

Comment: could you please add your directive code?

Comment: @pankajparkar directive added

Comment: @jme11 directive added to question

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`$http` returns a promise and is asynchronous. Your directive runs when your html renders. So what you do is don't render the HTML until you have the response.

HTML:

```
<div ng-if="ready"> 
   <div my-custom-directive></div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.ready = false;    
$http.get('/my-request').success(function(){
    $scope.ready = true;
});
```

This works because the `ng-if` directive will create the element only if the expression becomes true.

Comment: what if `flag` is already true and I want to run directive , if I'll make `flag = true` that will not run directive as `flag` was already `true`

Comment: Make it false intially then make true in success()

Comment: It will generate new HTML or show/hide same HTML that was existed initially

Comment: @saf ng-if always create/remove new html every time .It will not hide/show  the same html..Provide fiddle with it so that we can give you better solution. See this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177732/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-if-and-ng-show-ng-hide

Comment: Plunker added , pls check

Comment: yes it works but I have used $timeout b/w false and true so that directive have enough time to compute