# Angularjs and bootstrap pagination not hiding divs correctly

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am using Angularjs and pagination to show multiple divs. I am then hiding the divs based on some criteria. See code exract below

```
                <div class="DataItem" dir-paginate="x in parametersToDisplay | orderBy:'Name' | filter:textFilter | itemsPerPage: pageSize" current-page="currentPage" ng-hide="x.DetailLevel > detailLevel">                  
                    <label id="lblParameterName{{x.ConfigId}}" class="DataItemLabel">{{x.Name}}</label>
                    <label id="lblDescription{{x.ConfigId}}" class="DataItemLabel">{{x.Description}}</label>
                    <label id="lblUnits{{x.ConfigId}}" class="DataItemUnits">{{x.Units}}</label>
                    <input id="txtParameterValue{{x.ConfigId}}" class="DataItemValue" type="text" ng-blur="CheckCongigValue($event, x)" value="{{x.Value}}" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

The problem is that the divs that should be hidden are not visible but they still take the space. If I remove the pagination and just use a div with a ng-repeat it works fine and the hidden divs totally disappear.

I read that the bootstrap css for hidden uses display:hidden and overwrites the angularjs css which uses display:none. I also believe this can be overridden to correct the problem, but I have tried several things and can't seem to work it out.

Could someone give me a simple example showing how to do this.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

you have to use ng-if instead of ng-show/hide.

> The ngIf directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree based on an expression. If the expression assigned to ngIf evaluates to a false value then the element is removed from the DOM, otherwise a clone of the element is reinserted into the DOM.

[Good explaination here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177732/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-if-and-ng-show-ng-hide)

Comment: Thanks for your response, but if I replace ng-show with ng-if nothing gets shown. If I replace the criteria with true or false then it works. My criteria works with the ng-show.

Comment: you have to adapt you criteria, ng-if is positive, ng-hide is negative. So try ng-if="x.DetailLevel <= detailLevel"

Comment: I managed to sort out my criteria, but now ng-if does the same as ng-show and leaves the blanks where the hidden divs are. I am pretty sure I need to override the bootstrap css as it defines the hide differently, but not sure how to do this?

Comment: Also If I remove the pagination directives and just use a ng-repeat  and ng-show it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I manaed to fix it by producing a new array witht the filtered parameters that I wanted to display and then applied this to the pagination.

Its not the best solution but it works.