# ng-if not working, but ng-show works

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was trying to display items in a list with Angular js. I hope to organize the items with 3 items in a row with the following code:

```
  <div class='row-fluid' ng-repeat="region in regions" ng-show="$index % 3 == 0">

      <span  class='span4 checkbox'>
        <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="regions[$index].checked" ng-hide='regions[$index].text == null'> {{regions[$index].text}}
      </span>
      <span  class='span4 checkbox'>
        <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="regions[$index+1].checked" ng-hide='regions[$index+1].text == null'> {{regions[$index+1].text}}
      </span>
      <span  class='span4 checkbox'>
        <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="regions[$index+2].checked" ng-hide='regions[$index+2].text == null'> {{regions[$index+2].text}}
      </span>       
  </div>
```

If works fine when I use "ng-show". But when I switch it with 'ng-if', it doesn't work at all. (it shows all the 'regions' and does not filter with $index % 3 == 0). I was thinking "ng-if" should be a more standard way to implement my layout design but have no idea why it does not work at all.

Following is the code that won't work:

```
  <div class='row-fluid' ng-repeat="region in regions" ng-if="$index % 3 == 0">

      <span  class='span4 checkbox'>
        <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="regions[$index].checked" ng-hide='regions[$index].text == null'> {{regions[$index].text}}
      </span>
      <span  class='span4 checkbox'>
        <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="regions[$index+1].checked" ng-hide='regions[$index+1].text == null'> {{regions[$index+1].text}}
      </span>
      <span  class='span4 checkbox'>
        <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="regions[$index+2].checked" ng-hide='regions[$index+2].text == null'> {{regions[$index+2].text}}
      </span>       
  </div>
```

Could you please help me with that?

Comment: Please show the code that *doesn't* work. It's not useful to see the working code.

Comment: Where is not working code? Apart from your issue stated above, its worth to check the difference between ng-if and ng-show/hide. There is a strong reason what to opt. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177732/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-if-and-ng-show-ng-hide

Comment: @Juhana, I added the not-working code. The only difference is whether I used ng-if or ng-show

Comment: Did you try with ng-if="$index % 3 == '0'"

Comment: `ng-if` stops the html from making it to the DOM - if the HTML isn't there your `$index` wont be incremented how you think it will (at least that's what I *think* - explains the difference with `ngShow` to `ngIf`

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle ?

Comment: @immirza, yes, I tried, and it does not work either.

Comment: Which version you are using of angular js?

Answer (score 0):

Someone who is trying to find answer now...try having $index (or any variable that you have problem using with ng-if) declared into your controller first while using it with ng-if. Without that ng-if may be creating its own scope. For more info visit this question on stackoverflow.

1. [Why ng-show works with ng-repeat but ng-if doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32417143/why-ng-show-works-with-ng-repeat-but-ng-if-doesnt)
2. [ng-if not working, ng-show works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36357640/ng-if-not-working-ng-show-works)