# Why ng-show works with ng-repeat but ng-if doesn't?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple ng-repeat that displays only half of the items. For some reason, i got it to work with ng-show but not with ng-if. I don't understand why?

this works:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-show="$index < items.length / 2">{{item}}</li>
```

this doesn't:

```
  <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-if="$index < items.length / 2">{{item}}</li>
```

here is a jsfiddle to demonstrate:
http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/17269/

This question: [AngularJS: ng-if not working in combination with ng-click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19812116/angularjs-ng-if-not-working-in-combination-with-ng-click) does not provide an answer why ng-show works while ng-if doesn't

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19812116/angularjs-ng-if-not-working-in-combination-with-ng-click

Comment: try using a higher version that angular 1.01 and also use valid html. `<p>` is not valid child of `<ul>`

Comment: Solved by updating the angular version: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/17271/ While we have the chance to speak, why on earth did you update this jsfiddle **17269** times!? Don't click Update unless you want to share the fiddle with its current state, Run is enough for updating the fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing this is because of the Angular's priority rendering cycle. They might've changed its behavior with newer versions as someone posted above.
In case like yours I usually make a custom filter for ngRepeat to slice the array and show only specified number of items based on the offset (ngRepeat pagination). I've never messed up with using `ngRepeat` directly with `ngIf` or `ngShow/Hide` as it can get really bugged whichever way you turn it.

- `ngRepeat` directive creates and appends new node elements.
- `ngShow` will allow angular to generate an element, but after that it will set it's display to `none`.
- `ngIf` won't allow angular to generate an element.

As far as I know, `ngIf` has higher priority than `ngRepeat`, so I can assume that what's happening below the field is:

> - Angular sees the array.
> - ngIf doesn't know what $index (as it's part of `ngRepeat`) is so its cycle just runs by.
> - ngRepeat renders elements.

whilst `ngShow` works:

> - Angular sees the array.
> - ngRepeat renders elements.
> - ngShow shows them by specified condition.

Comment: got it now! thanks for all who replied!