# ng-if not working, ng-show works

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ng-if

I have an html where I must show `AngularJS` template only when I reach the bottom of the page (I've implemented infinite scrolling).

The first page comes from the server. So I've to put an `ng-if` for that first page, because the user could have a bookmark with "address/page=5", and the html template for the first page from the server doesn't have to be in the page.

Now I have the url "address", specific for the page from the server.

`ng-if` doesn't work, the page is empty, but if I use `ng-show` it all works fine.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div id="itemsGrid" ng-controller="aCtrl" infinite-scroll='item_gallery.nextPage()' infinite-scroll-distance='1' infinite-scroll-disabled=''> 

        <div ng-show="server_page()"> 
        //here the first page template
```

**JS**

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, ItemGallery) {
    $scope.item_gallery = new ItemGallery();
    ...
}

myApp.factory('ItemGallery', function($http) {
    var ItemGallery = function() {
    ...
        ItemGallery.prototype.nextPage = function() {
        ...
        }
    return ItemGallery;
}
```

If I do comment

```
//$scope.item_gallery = new ItemGallery();
```

ng-if works fine, the page is correctly showed.

The page is showed when I use: ng-if + line commented, ng-show.

**NOTE:**

`ng-if="true"` doesn't work, it's not a problem of the function used, `ng-if="server_page()"`
I don't want to use ng-show.

Why `ng-if` doesn't work? What's the problem with that line? How can I make it working?

Comment: can u add a fiddle/pluner to this please, is easier to follow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've the solution.

Console was saying me:

> Cannot read property 'rel' of null.

This happened because the first thing I was doing inside `var ItemGallery = function()`, was to change the `href` for the next page (next page comes from ajax request). The `href` for the next page is located within a `<div>` in the bottom of the current page.

The point is that I'm changing the `href` for the next page, BEFORE the current page has been loaded.

So..

```
window.onload = function () {
                this.nextPageQueryString = document.getElementById("nextPage").rel;

                this.next_href = this.domain_url + this.nextPageQueryString;
            };
```

NOTE: this has solved my problem, but I find it very strange.
`ng-if` wasn't able to see the 'rel' property for the next `href` and I got the empty page. Now Angular can see the 'rel' property and it all works fine.

ng-if should work apart of what I have in the html.

I still can't understand the behavior of `ng-if`.

Answer (score 4):

ng-if creates a new child scope

to keep a watch on model in ng if the thumb rule is:

DON'T USE SCOPE AS MODEL e.g.

```
ng-if='showStuff' //here my scope is model **INCORRECT**
ng-if='someObject.showStuff' // ** CORRECT **
```

use an object property in ng-model then even if ng-if creates the new child scope parent scope will have the changes.

on the other hand ng-show does not create new child scope it works in parent scope.

in you case please change

```
$scope.item_gallery = new ItemGallery();
```

to

```
$scope.someObject.item_gallery = new ItemGallery();
```

then it should work.

Comment: doesn't work for me, but I'll think about it, thanks