# Show or Hide Dom Element based on Ng-value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a view of quotes rendered from Angular as a resource. I have part of the quote hidden but upon clicking the rest of the quote is shown. The problem I have is getting the body of the quote to toggle correctly.

I have it set up so in the angular controller the dom elements visibility is toggled on click between hidden and visible. My current code has a few bugs (it's late and I'm having brain farts)

My problem is I'm self learning and If I don't ask it takes me hours to figure these things out. My current ng-value sets ShowMe and if it == true, all of the other quote bodies are shown. Any assistance would be appreciated.

1. Basically what I'm trying to do again is have the quote body hidden
   on page load.
2. If a quote is click show the body of that quote.
3. If it is clicked again hide the body of that quote.

**Angular**

```
  app.controller("QuotesCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', 'Quotes', 'Quote', '$location',  function($scope, $http, Quotes, Quote, $location ) {
        $scope.quotes = Quotes.query();
        $scope.quote = Quote.query();

        $scope.switchQuote = function (id) {
            if(document.getElementById('quotebody' + id).style.visibility == 'hidden') {
             document.getElementById('quotebody' + id).style.visibility = 'visible' 
             $scope.showMe = true; 
            } else {
                document.getElementById('quotebody' + id).style.visibility = 'hidden'
                $scope.showMe = false; 
            }   
        }
    }
]);
```

**html**

```
<div class="quotes col-xs-10 col-md-8" ng-controller="QuotesCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat="quote in quotes">
        <a ng-click="switchQuote(quote.id)" ng-value="showMe">
          <span>Quote id: {{quote.id}}</span>
          <span>Name: {{quote.name}}</span>
          <span>Email: {{quote.email}}</span>
          <span>City: {{quote.city}}</span>
        </a>
        <div id="quotebody{{quote.id}}" ng-show="showMe">
          <span>City: {{quote}}</span>
          <span>City: {{quote.city}}</span>
          <span>City: {{quote.city}}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: perhaps this is what you want https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

Comment: Or even better https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide which provides the same functionality as your code (ngIf modifies the DOM)

Comment: I think you have mixed up [ngValue](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue) with [ngIf](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)/[ngShow](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow). Take a look at:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177732/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-if-and-ng-show-ng-hide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use ng-show or ng-if for this. With the switchQuote function you will switch the value from true to false and vice versa.

Since you probably have a lot of quotes and they are in an ng-repeat, you should use the property (in my example, property "visible") on each quote object to show or hide the clicked quote.

Html:

```
<div class="quotes col-xs-10 col-md-8" ng-controller="QuotesCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="quote in quotes">
    <a ng-click="switchQuote(quote)">
      <span>Quote id: {{quote.id}}</span>
      <span>Name: {{quote.name}}</span>
      <span>Email: {{quote.email}}</span>
      <span>City: {{quote.city}}</span>
    </a>
    <div ng-show="quote.visible">
      <span>City: {{quote}}</span>
      <span>City: {{quote.city}}</span>
      <span>City: {{quote.city}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller("QuotesCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', 'Quotes', 'Quote', '$location',  function($scope, $http, Quotes, Quote, $location ) {
    $scope.quotes = Quotes.query();
    $scope.quote = Quote.query();

    $scope.switchQuote = function (quote) {
        quote.visible = !quote.visible;
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Very thankful for your answer. I dont think I would have wrote clean code like this for a few weeks. It really is appreciated.