# Use html ID with angularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a four tables that populates data using ng-repeat and I have some validation to show one table or another depending on a radio button selection.

I call a CSS id in the table called "fixtable". The issue is that if I remove the **ng-if** of any of the tables it works, the header is fixed but I need those validations to show or hide the tables.

It looks like angular dont recognize the "id" property or I dont know.

Any help on this, Im in a hurry.

```
<div  ng-if="topTable.value === 'topCategory'" ng-show="loadViewCategories">
  <table class="table" id="fixTable">
      some code
  </table>

<div  ng-if="topTable.value === 'topBrand'" ng-show="loadViewBrand">
  <table class="table" id="fixTable2">
      some code
  </table>
```

Inside the HTML I call my function to make the fiexd header like this

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fixTable").tableHeadFixer();
    $("#fixTable2").tableHeadFixer();
    $("#fixTable3").tableHeadFixer();
    $("#fixTable4").tableHeadFixer();
 });
</script>
```

And I have some CSS that makes my table scrollable all the way to the right

```
    #fixTable {
    width: 2700px !important;
}
#fixTable2 {
    width: 2700px !important;
}
#fixTable3 {
    width: 2700px !important;
}
#fixTable4 {
    width: 2700px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `ng-if="topTable.value === 'topCategory'"` remove your table from the DOM, so when you call `$("#ID").tableHeadFixer();`, it doesn't work on the tables not present in the DOM.

You have two solutions:

1. remove your `ng-if`, and use a `ng-show` instead, because ng-show keep your table in the DOM, it only make it not visible. Note that there is others important differences between those two directives, you can learn more about them on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177732/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-if-and-ng-show-ng-hide)
2. each time you change `topTable.value`, call the `tableHeadFixer()` to make it works

Comment: The first option is like using ng-show twice in the same line?
ng-show="topTable.value === 'topCategory'" and ng-show="loadViewCategories" ??

and for the second option, where can I call the tableHeadFixer()
Thanks for your time.

Comment: I have something like this for each radio button:

<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" ng-model="topTable.value" value="topCategory" ng-change="updateTotals(topTable.value)">TY Top 30 Categories</label

Comment: @kennechu You can't use ng-show twice on the same element, you have to use it this way : `ng-show="topTable.value === 'topCategory' && loadViewCategories"`. For the second option, you can call the tableHeadFixer() in your updateTotals function