# Angular expression order of execution (hierachical div's with ng-if) seem to not work as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ng-if

I have an angular snippet that can be simplified to this view:

```
<div ng-if="vm.selectedItem !== null">

    <div ng-if="vm.selectedItem.someProperty !== null">         
    </div>

</div>
```

I expect that internal div would not execute it's expression if the top div is not added to DOM based on ng-if, but in reality I get `Cannot read property 'someProperty' of null` when something changes.

Is it the default behavior of angular and there are not guarantee on the order here and I cannot rely on the outer div ng-if's?

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible. https://jsfiddle.net/hb1pfs39/

Answer (score 2):

Beware: `ng-if` creates it's own scope...

You could use `ng-show` instead of `ng-if`: it doesn't create child scope...

Comment: Yes, I have done that already, I just wanted to understand why this is happening. I was also using ng-if since it's more "efficient" as far as I understand (don't render dom compare to not showing it)

Comment: I think ng-if will not avoid rendering DOM (it is built before angular takes place...), but it **removes** elements from the DOM, if the condition is not met... So, no, it probably will not be *faster*... (see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177732/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-if-and-ng-show-ng-hide).