# Is it correct that one-time-binding re-evaluates variable when combined with ngIf directive? - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

One of my mates in work show me a really weird behavior of one-time binding in angular.

**UseCase:**

When you have an **element which text is binding** by that **one-time** binding inside block which is **conditional by ng-if**, then if we change that value, for example adding some letters, and later change the condition of ng-if, and after that the value from **one-time binding has been refreshed**.

**HTML:**

```
  <div ng-if="a" class="blue">{{ ::text }}</div>
```

It is a kind of bug, or expected behaviour?

Here is an **example** of what I'm doing: http://codepen.io/samot/pen/rLJAdN

Comment: As @jjmotes answer  you are reevaluting the expression

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the condition of `ng-if` is made false and then true, it will recreate its contents, causing the one-time `ng-bind` directive to be evaluated again.

The only thing one time binding does is to avoid adding a watch on your expression, but it doesn't "cache" or "store" the result for the case the content of a directive is compiled again.

So it's expected behavior.

Comment: Yeah, i know that, but there is a kind of bug, or expected behaviour?

Comment: It's expected behavior. Imagine your content is inside ng-repeat using a list. Whenever the list changes and rows are created or recreated, they are evaluated again even if the expressions are one-time bindings.

Comment: If you were using `ng-show` instead of `ng-if` the value wouldn't change, since this time the content would just change visibility instead of being recreated.

Comment: If you don't like this behavior just make ng-if one-time binding `ng-if="::a"`

Look at you HTML when running angular app. ng-show only define display:none on element whereas ng-if compile html each time it changes condition.

Answer (score 2):

**Works as expected** because using `ngIf` directive the code is completely recompiled. If you use `ngShow` the behavior changes and code behaves as you are expecting from ngIf. This because code is [only hidden and not recompiled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177732/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-if-and-ng-show-ng-hide), so not causing the re-(first)-evaluation of the variable.