# AngularJS ng-if not deleting element after $compile

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-compile

I have a directive that does the following:

1. Adds another directive attribute to the element.
2. Removes its own attribute.
3. Calls `$compile()` on the element to make AngularJS re-compile the element so the new directive is attached.

This works fine, except when I also add an ng-if to the element. See this minimal example and follow the steps below to demonstrate.

https://embed.plnkr.co/ymk0RwGopGF1KvesWmvA/

1. Press `+` any number of times to add to "count".
2. Press `0` to reset "count".
3. Press `+` any number of times again.

I'd expect the "my-test shown" `<p>` tag to be deleted from the DOM once its `ng-if` condition is no longer true after step #2. Instead, it stays around, and you'll see an extra copy of the message after step #3.

I assume calling `$compile($element)($scope);` in the my-test directive link function is having some unintended consequence, but I don't understand what's going on here. Any ideas?

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have answered, the short solution is to use `ng-show` instead of `ng-if` or to not use `$compile` like that.  With that aside, you might have your good reasons why you would want to use `ng-if` and `$compile` like this.

This question interested me on the note of using `$compile` with an isolate scope from `ng-if`.  I did a bit of experimenting with [this fork](https://plnkr.co/edit/TcDDQLprpU2f910bhQVS) and will try to explain what I found.

We already know `ng-if` creates an isolate scope, but then passing that element with `ng-if` on it through `$compile` creates *another* isolate scope (and would make the newly compiled `ng-if` be looking at variables on the first-round isolate scope - the directive's `$scope` value).

To re-iterate that, we're having some scopes looking like (value in [] is scope.$id):

1. main/outer controller has `scope[2]`
2. `ng-if my-test` element has `ng-if` looking at `scope[2].count` and creates `scope[3]`
3. `my-test` linker therefore has `$scope.$id == 3;`
4. `my-test` does `$compile` - **recompiled `ng-if` element: creates new isolate `scope[4]` and is looking at `scope[3].count`**
5. when `scope[2].count` hits 0 - `scope[3]` gets `$destroyed` (because `scope[3]` was created by that first `ng-if` which is still lingering around somewhere) ... BUT!  the element is A. still there and B. its count isn't updating - WHY?

Well because the element that's still there is the one that was `$compiled` and has A. an `ng-if` looking at `scope[3].count` (which is now $destroyed) and B. its own new isolate `scope[4]` (created by re-compiling `ng-if` element with parent `scope[3]`)

So ya.  That is all very confusing and you might just be asking... well how do I fix this??

**TL;DR;**

The simplest solution:
`$element.removeAttr('ng-if');` before you do `$compile($element)($scope);`

If you've been following along, this works because the original `ng-if` is still looking at `scope[2].count`, and the element that is present is no longer getting a second isolate scope.

Comment: That was very helpful, thanks. Do other built-in directives create an isolated scope like ng-if? Am I likely to hit this same issue again if I happen to use ng-repeat or even a custom/3rd party directive alongside my directive?

Comment: Glad that it was helpful!  Some built-in and 3rd party directives do create isolate scope.  You will just need to review the docs for each directive you plan to use.  For example, [ng-if docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) say "This directive creates new scope."  (under Directive Info section)  As do the [ng-repeat docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat), but you will see [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) (for example) does not.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can understand, when you change the value of count with 0, your directive is destroyed before changing the value of `count`. So that unremoved directive's count value is still 1.

If you use ngShow instead of ngIf, you can solve this. Because ngShow attribute doesn't trigger $destroy event and doesn't remove element from your view. So that directive can catch new value of that `count`. Or you can use `prelink` instead of `link` for catching updating of value of `count`.

Comment: I also tried ng-show prior to posting, and I agree it solves the problem in the minimalistic example. In my real app, however, there are situations which require actually using ng-if, such as for form inputs that are required when visible.

Comment: @DavidSmith now I remembered. You can renamed that `link` property with `prelink`. After this changing, your ngIf will be able to catch the value of `count`. You can solve this by this way.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know how to explain properly but ng-if adds a new scope to the element, his own scope, check this so question to see more details: [what is the difference between ng-if and ng-show/ng-hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177732/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-if-and-ng-show-ng-hide). I tried with ng-show and it worked the way you want:

```
ng-show="count > 0"
```

Hope it helps =)