# Is ng-if not evaluated or I do not understand about ng-view clearly

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if, ng-view

Go straight to the code and I will explain more along the question

I have the index.html file like this:

```
<body class="horizontal-menu">
<!-- Preloader -->
<div id="preloader">
    <div id="status"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></div>
</div>
<div ng-if="isLoading">
    <div id="status"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></div>
</div>
<section>
        <div class="contentpanel">
            <!-- content goes here... -->
            <error-page ng-if="error"></error-page>
            <div ng-view ng-if="!isLoading && !error"></div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- mainpanel -->
</section>

</body>
```

I want to implement the indicator for my page, you can see the `<div id="status"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></div>` as well as `ng-if="isLoading"` line.

In the `login` component I have these line of code to change from `login` view to `register` view.

```
$scope.onRegister = function () {
    $rootScope.isLoading = true;
    $location.path(routes.REGISTER);
}
```

What I want is when changing the view from `login` view to `register` view, the indicator (spinner) is up. After that, in the `register component` code I have these lines to force the spinner off.

```
function registerController($scope, $rootScope, $location, $http) {
    $rootScope.isLoading = false;
}
```

But the spinner rounds endlessly.

I tried to read about `$viewContentLoaded`, and I put these line of code in my application (parent application) as well as the `register` controller.

```
$rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function (event) {
    $rootScope.isLoading = false;
})
```

It still does not help.

Many thanks in advance for helping me solving that issue.

Comment: where is $scope.error in controller?

Comment: I think about that case of something wrong with the `error` variable. I just removed it out of `ng-if="!isLoading && !error"` line. The problem is still there :(

Comment: I also want to ask if any problem with my approach ?

Comment: can you create a plunker?

Comment: I am quite not familiar with some tool like plunker/jsfidle, I think it is quite difficult to reproduce my case in those tool. But I will try. With a first look on my code, did you saw some problem?

Comment: if you can give team viewer i can check

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer might answer your question that explains how ng-if works:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19177773/5018962

In short:

The ngIf directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree based on an expression. If the expression assigned to ngIf evaluates to a false value then the element is removed from the DOM, otherwise a clone of the element is reinserted into the DOM.