# Angularjs ng-if is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Appreciate if anyone could help explain why my checkbox Voted: is not able to control the ng-if directive? However, it is workable for the Keep HTML: check box

```
<p>
  <li ng-repeat="x in info">
    {{x.name}} Voted:
    <input type="checkbox"
      ng-model="myVar"
      ng-init="myVar =true">
  </li>
</p>

<input type="checkbox" ng-model="myVar" ng-init="myVar =true">
<h1 ng-if="myVar">Welcome2</h1>
<script>
  var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
  app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.myObj = {
      "color": "white",
      "background-color": "coral",
      "font-size": "60px",
      "padding": "50px"
    }

    $scope.info = [{
      name: 'woon',
      age: '18'
    },
    {
      name: 'amir',
      age: '17'
    }];
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Why the binding to `myVar` multiple times, its in both the repeat loop as well as the input underneath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use ng-show. 
Working example:

```
ng-show="myVar"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f8cjv7eL/

[what is the difference between ng-if and ng-show/ng-hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177732/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-if-and-ng-show-ng-hide)

Comment: thanks for message, on the basis of  woon Voted check or amir Voted check i want to show Welcome2 like Keep HTML

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. In that loop you are binding multiple times to the same variable, that's wrong.

Comment: Okay based on checkbox check and uncheck i want to display Welcome2 message. like we are doing for Keep HTML check and uncheck. I want to do the same for woon and amir checkbox

Comment: The problem is probably the scope inside the ng-repeat. Do you want to show one message next to each checkbox or 1 in general?

Comment: If i check any checkbox it will show Welcome2 else hide Welcome2

Comment: Here you have a rough example, I can't think of anything else right now. http://jsfiddle.net/1rL6zpqh/

Comment: Yes some thing like this but can't we do the same in my code without making so many changes. ?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use template variables for that, use scope.myVar that way you can change it any time depending on , by the way, myVar is out of loop, you have 2 options

1) extract that value in JS part (only if the value is being calculated)
2) move that input into the loop (if you need to display an input for every record on the array)