# code in directive's controller runing although it is hidden via ng-hide

Tags: angularjs

In this example:

```
<div ng-hide="hideMe">
   <my-directive></my-directive>
</div>
```

I would like the code in the controller for `myDirective`, not to run when `hideMe === true`.

Is there a way to do this  rather than wrapping all the code of the controller in an `if (!hideMe === true)` statement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ngHide`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) simply hide the element, but if you want it not to be run you should use [`ngIf`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) instead. According to the docs, [`ngIf`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)  removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree (i.e., no element, no directive and no controller) but [`ngHide`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) only change its visibility.

```
<div ng-if="hideMe">
   <my-directive></my-directive>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should actually go for `ng-if` directive as the the code inside does not get evaluated if the condition is false. You could refer to the following link for better understanding.

[what is the difference between ng-if and ng-show/ng-hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177732/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-if-and-ng-show-ng-hide)