# Select multiple radio options in angularjs issue

Tags: angularjs, html, select, checkbox, radio-button

I want to select multiple radio options.New to angularjs.

Steps to produce the issue:

1. Select any country from the 1st select menu -> Choose Reason A
2. Select any country from the 2nd select menu -> Choose Reason C

here the above Reason A option disappears and only Reason C is selected. 
i want to hold the two different reasons for different countries section.

here is the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Lini7/knfsv64m/8/

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
$scope.showReasonA = function showReasonA(checkNoTin) {
    console.log("print the notin value from data",this.item.noTin);
    if (!this.item.country) return false;
    var selectedCountry = this.item.country.country.toLowerCase();
    var fourCountries = ["cayman islands", "albania"]
    var isIt = fourCountries.indexOf(selectedCountry) >= 0;
    console.log("print match country val",isIt);
    console.log("get checknotin value before assign",checkNoTin);
    if (checkNoTin) this.item.noTin = true;
    console.log("final checknotin val",checkNoTin);
    return isIt;
  }
});
```

and the view

```
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
<select name="country_0" ng-model="item.country" ng-options="" required="required" class="ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched" style=""><option value="" selected="selected"></option><option label="AFGHANISTAN" value="object:835">AFGHANISTAN</option><option label="cayman islands" value="object:836">cayman islands</option><option label="ALBANIA" value="object:837">ALBANIA</option><option label="ALGERIA" value="object:838">ALGERIA</option><option label="AMERICAN SAMOA" value="object:839">AMERICAN SAMOA</option></select>
<div class="row">
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.noTin" ng-disabled="item.tin" ng-checked="showReasonA(true)" ng-required="item.noTin" name="checkboxNoTin"/>
  </label><span translate="transactions.changeAddress.crs.yes.me_no_tin" style="margin-top: 10px" class="col-value"></span>
</div>
<div ng-if="item.noTin" class="row">
  <div class="col padding-top-xs"><span translate="transactions.changeAddress.crs.select_reason" style="margin-bottom: 12px;" class="pol-value col-value"></span>
    <div ng-if="item.country.tin == true" ng-init="item.reason = 0" class="row margin-bottom-medium">
      <label class="radio-button">
        <input type="radio" name="reason" ng-model="item.reason" ng-value="A" required="required"/><span class="indicator"></span><span translate="transactions.changeAddress.crs.yes.reason1"></span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="!showReasonA()" class="row margin-bottom-medium">
      <div class="col">
        <label class="radio-button">
          <input type="radio" name="reason" ng-model="item.reason" ng-value="B" required="required"/><span class="indicator"></span><span translate="transactions.changeAddress.crs.yes.reason2_title"></span>
          <label class="item item-input input-margin">
            <textarea  ng-model="item.othersReason" ng-required="item.reason == 2" rows="5"></textarea>
          </label>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="!showReasonA()" class="row margin-bottom-medium">
      <div class="col">
        <label class="radio-button">
          <input type="radio" name="reason" ng-model="item.reason" ng-value="C" required="required"/><span class="indicator"></span><span translate="transactions.changeAddress.crs.yes.reason3"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<select name="country_0" ng-model="item.country" ng-options="" required="required" class="ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched" style=""><option value="" selected="selected"></option><option label="AFGHANISTAN" value="object:835">AFGHANISTAN</option><option label="cayman islands" value="object:836">cayman islands</option><option label="ALBANIA" value="object:837">ALBANIA</option><option label="ALGERIA" value="object:838">ALGERIA</option><option label="AMERICAN SAMOA" value="object:839">AMERICAN SAMOA</option></select>
<div class="row">
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.noTin" ng-disabled="item.tin" ng-checked="showReasonA(true)" ng-required="item.noTin" name="checkboxNoTin"/>
  </label><span translate="transactions.changeAddress.crs.yes.me_no_tin" style="margin-top: 10px" class="col-value"></span>
</div>
<div ng-if="item.noTin" class="row">
  <div class="col padding-top-xs"><span translate="transactions.changeAddress.crs.select_reason" style="margin-bottom: 12px;" class="pol-value col-value"></span>
    <div ng-if="item.country.tin == true" ng-init="item.reason = 0" class="row margin-bottom-medium">
      <label class="radio-button">
        <input type="radio" name="reason" ng-model="item.reason" ng-value="A" required="required"/><span class="indicator"></span><span translate="transactions.changeAddress.crs.yes.reason1"></span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="!showReasonA()" class="row margin-bottom-medium">
      <div class="col">
        <label class="radio-button">
          <input type="radio" name="reason" ng-model="item.reason" ng-value="B" required="required"/><span class="indicator"></span><span translate="transactions.changeAddress.crs.yes.reason2_title"></span>
          <label class="item item-input input-margin">
            <textarea ng-model="item.othersReason" ng-required="item.reason == 2" rows="5"></textarea>
          </label>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="!showReasonA()" class="row margin-bottom-medium">
      <div class="col">
        <label class="radio-button">
          <input type="radio" name="reason" ng-model="item.reason" ng-value="C" required="required"/><span class="indicator"></span><span translate="transactions.changeAddress.crs.yes.reason3"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lini7/knfsv64m/8/

Comment: You want to select multiple radio options or set default checkbox and radio button on page load? Could you elaborate the issue you are facing?

Comment: @SaravananSachi added my comments.please check

Comment: what do you want actually ?? and your requirement is not clear @Lini

Comment: @BOSS i have separate radio buttons for each country selection. How to select radio buttons in each section. Currently am able to select only one radio button

Comment: @Lini You specified all the radio buttons with same name "reason". To select multiple radio buttons, use different name. Using the same names, groups the radio button into one.

Comment: You are correct. can you provide the sample example. I am new to angularjs and am hard to find this in angularjs

Answer (score 1):

To make some input as hidden you can use

```
<p ng-show="condition">I'm shown</p>
```

and this condition value should be initialized in the scope of your controller

```
$scope.condition=true/false
```

to hide an show input you can use ng-if. Its better to use ng-if for dynamic inputs . see details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177732/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-if-and-ng-show-ng-hide)

Now for your case you can use `item.reason` in the condition to show and hide your input .

```
<input type="radio" name="reason" ng-model="item.other" ng-value="C" required="required" ng-if="item.reason='object:836'" />
```

Comment: @Lini see my answer this might help you

Comment: my issue is only one radio button is selected. In the second country list i have the same reason options to select but if i select any one the first country option disappears. i want to hold the two reasons for different countries.

Comment: you should rename the model then giving same model will not work

Comment: renaming the model for what? i do not want the solution to hide my radio button. I want to know how to make group of radio buttons and select one from each country section http://jsfiddle.net/Lini7/knfsv64m/10/ latest fiddle

Comment: yeah now I got you.. I would suggest you post two or three question for each of your problem .. :) .. so that its clear still the question is broad

Comment: you  should not change your question time after time :) .. its not expected that people will answer your question then you will change it :( which will make the answers and efforts  invalid :(

Comment: Thanks for your comments. by this time i can learn the angularjs from classroom instead of just seeing your comments not the solutions

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the solution

I just added the radio button name with index then it worked which will give different names for each group of buttons.

> name='reason_{{$index}}'