# What is the difference between *ngIf and [hidden]?

Tags: angular

Say I check it against and expression, then aren't these two same ?

```html
<div *ngIf="expression">{{val}}</div>

<div [hidden]="!expression">{{val}}</div>
```

Comment: Pretty much the same as angularjs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177732/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-if-and-ng-show-ng-hide

Comment: The question itself helped me to notice that I forgot to invert the boolean condition :-)

Answer (score 102):

There is actually a performance difference between them:

**ngIf** will comment out the data if the expression is false. This way the data are not even loaded, causing HTML to load faster.

**[hidden]** will load the data and mark them with the *hidden* HTML attribute. This way data are loaded even if they are not visible.

So *[hidden]* is better used when we want the show/hide status to change frequently, for example on a button click event, so we do not have to load the data every time the button is clicked, just changing its *hidden* attribute would be enough.

Note that the performance difference may not be visible with small data, only with larger objects.

Comment: Agreed! ngIf shouldn't be considered when working with larger data to be rendered often.  ngIf can be considered in cases where the page is extremely larger and we need to render large data through an API call or something. When we work with just the already rendered page's sections like navbars, hidden attribute is way faster.

Comment: The difference is even bigger when images are inside the ngIf block. It seems that on Safari (iOS iphone), the images may be reloaded each time which considerably reduces performances. So if you can have choice between ngIf and hidden, prefer hidden. Definitely.

Answer (score 42):

[`ngIf` is a structural directive](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html), it creates/destroys content inside the DOM. The second statement just hides/shows the content with css, i.e. adding/removing `display:none` to the element's style.

> #### What are structural directives?
>
> Structural directives are responsible for HTML layout. They shape or
>   reshape the DOM's structure, typically by adding, removing, or
>   manipulating elements.

---

In the first case if expression is `false` then `div` and it's content won't be created. In the second case `div` and content are always created but they are not *visible* if the expression is `false`.

Answer (score 19):

There is actually another difference between them when you try to manipulate elements within the structures that are wrapped within a section:

**ngIf** will cause an undefined error in your code if you try reference an element within that section when is false.

**[hidden]** will not cause an undefined error in your code if you try to reference an element within the section, when that section is hidden.

So [hidden] is better used when we want to operate on elements within the wrapped section.

Comment: yulp, can't agree more.

Comment: This was the reason I found this answer. I was trying to reference a table with a template ref  (eg: #searchResults) from an external search button. When trying to hide the grid when no results are found, I was getting an error. The hidden was a good option because the user would probably search multiple time until he finds what he wants and I am always able to reference things from outside the scope of elements that should be hidden. Very good.

Comment: Glad it helped you https://stackoverflow.com/users/692083/m%c3%a1rio-meyrelles  -- I have to return here to remind myself every now and then :-)

Answer (score 15):

*ngIf if false will remove the element from the DOM

Hidden if true will set the display to none in css

Answer (score 4):

An additional key point, it may break mat-paginator who is inside of a `*ngIf` block. For example

.HTML

```
<div *ngIf="myCondition">
    <mat-paginator #seeMe ...></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

.TS

```
this.dataSource.paginator = this.seeMe;  // seeMe becomes underfined
```

> Solution: <div [hidden]="!myCondition">

Answer (score 2):

*ngIf will include and remove the element from the DOM if set to true and false respectively. [hidden] in angular2 is the equivalent of ngshow and nghide that we had in AngularJS.It just shows and hides the element by add display:none and display:block.

Answer (score -3):

**Scenario** :--> suppose you are using Behaviorsubject, and it emits boolean value "true/false".

**Case 1** --> *ngIf --> if Behaviorsubject returns initial value false, then it will disappear that DOM. and even if it emits true value later, it wont be visible.

**Case 2** --> Hidden --> it will work perfectly based on Behaviorsubject's emited value. i.e it will toggle the DOM.

**Note** - *ngIf also toggles the DOM but on user's action or DOM event that toggles value of ngIf.

Comment: Behaviorsubject is not mentioned in this question.