# MatSort is not working properly

Tags: angular, angular-material2

MatSort is not working properly. I have imported the MatSort module from @angular/material. MatSort is working only for first 2 rows.

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="slno">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> SL NO. </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = index"> {{i+1}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="project">
       <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> PROJECT</mat-header-cell>
       <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.project_name}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

TS:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'project',
  templateUrl: './project.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./project.component.css']
})
export class ProjectComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns = ['slno', 'project', 'startdate', 'enddate', 'action'];
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
ngOnInit() {
  //get data
  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);
  this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
     this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}
```

Comment: share typescript file

Comment: @Component({
  selector: 'project',
  templateUrl: './project.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./project.component.css']
})
export class ProjectComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns = ['slno', 'project', 'startdate', 'enddate', 'action'];
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

ngOnInit() {
//get data
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the `mat-row`, try the below code

**HTML:**

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="slno">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> SL NO. </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = index"> {{i+1}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="project">
       <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> PROJECT</mat-header-cell>
       <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.project_name}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

**TS:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'table-sorting-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-sorting-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-sorting-example.html',
})
export class TableSortingExample {
  displayedColumns = ['slno', 'project'];

 //this will be your projects data
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);

  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  /**
   * Set the sort after the view init since this component will
   * be able to query its view for the initialized sort.
   */
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
}
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qe3bjf-ukzbt2?file=app/table-sorting-example.ts

Comment: can you create a repro in this stackblitz? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qe3bjf

Comment: Can you please revise the question?.  I include ts file

Comment: in that question, I don't find <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>

Comment: please revise one more time

Comment: can you share the `json data` for  `data` variable ?

Comment: [
0
:
{id: 61, project_name: "sss", project_type: "Billable", project_code: "sysPR/032/3/29/2018", status: "Drafted", …}
1
:
{id: 60, project_name: "dd", project_type: "Billable", project_code: "sysPR/031/3/29/2018", status: "Drafted", …}]

Comment: Working example added in the answer

Comment: Working example run properly. But it only sort first 2 rows when applied to my code. I revised several times. But cant find the solution

Comment: then its some issue with some other code which you didn't post here, thats why I told you to replicate the same in the stackblitz with offline data (full data) url: stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qe3bjf

Comment: Updated working code in answer. `SLNo` column won't sort because thats not there in ur `DataSource`. Now Projectname is sorting