# Angular material - mat table - sort and filter do not work?

Tags: angular, html-table, angular-material

I have a problem with mat-table from angular material.
I can't get the sort and the filter to work. (I think I do exactly like the doc..)

Here my code :

My component :

```
   listPatientsStay: PatientStay[] = [
        {lastName: 'lastname1', firstName: 'firstname1', sex: 'f', birthDate: '1990-01-01'},
        {lastName: 'lastname2', firstName: 'firstname2', sex: 'm', birthDate: '1990-01-01'},
        {lastName: 'lastname3', firstName: 'firstname3', sex: 'f', birthDate: '1990-01-01'}
      ];
    displayedColumns: string[] = ['lastName', 'firstName', 'sex', 'birthDate'];
    dataSource;
    @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

    ngOnInit() {
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<PatientStay>(this.listPatientsStay);
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    }

 applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    console.log('Apply filter', filterValue);
    filterValue = filterValue.trim();
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase();
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
  }
```

My template :

```
<mat-form-field class="half-width">
          <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)"  placeholder="Filter">
</mat-form-field>

 <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="lastName">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Lastname</mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.lastName}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="firstName">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Firstname</mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.firstName}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="sex">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Sex</mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.sex}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="birthDate">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Birthdate</mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.birthDate | date: 'dd.MM.yyyy'}}</mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
                 (click)="onRowClicked(row)"></mat-row>

 </mat-table>
```

Have imported :
MatTableModule
MatSortModule

Have 0 error but it just doesn't filter and doesn't sort.

Thanks for the help ..

Comment: Does the filter work if you disable the sorting functionality?

Comment: nop unfortunatly ..

Comment: could you please mark the question as answered, if it one of the answers below answers your question?

Answer (score 1):

Its a simple Spelling Mistake:

The parameter is 'this.listPatientsStay', but the property is called 'listPatientStay'.
The ngOnInit Method should look like:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<PatientStay>(this.listPatientStay);
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}
```

Checkout on Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hrdv2z

In general the Question [Mat-table Sorting Demo not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46893164/mat-table-sorting-demo-not-working?rq=1) explains why its necessary to include the MatSortModule.

Comment: This is not loading the data at all

Comment: no i just did a mistake when i wrote in this post. my code is ok. i see the tab and all its contain, still have prob with sort and filter

Comment: @Helene ok, lets see, does the Stackblitz snippet work for you?
The Code Snippet you send, with the fix, does the filter technique as expected.
If the code doesnt work in your project i think the cause is somewhere else in the project and i would need some more information to help you.

Answer (score 0):

correct spell mistake.add this --> this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.listPatientStay);

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
When I comment pagination part of the code it works (filter AND sort)
thanks at the people who tried to help me

I will work on that pagination problem now ;)

Comment: I have pagination here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-with-multi-queries.  Maybe that will help.