# Sorting using mat-table for nested properties

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, mat-table

I have the following table

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation">

<!-- Name Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="employee.name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let employeeWrapper">{{employeeWrapper.employee.name}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> ID </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let employeeWrapper">{{employeeWrapper.id}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="tableColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: tableColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48509392/1393400), `matColumnDef` and the **object property** must have the same name.

I got it right for `employeeWrapper.id` and the sort is working.

But for `employeeWrapper.employee.name`, it's a second level property. Setting the `matColumnDef` to `employee.name` or `name` does not work. I've tried both.

Is there a solution/workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can write a little helper function to compute the value of a nested property given its path, and use it to override the default `sortingDataAccessor` of your `dataSource`, something like

```
getPropertyByPath(obj: Object, pathString: string){
  return pathString.split('.').reduce((o, i) => o[i], obj);
}

dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (data, sortHeaderId: string) => {
  return getPropertyByPath(data, sortHeaderId);
};
```

You also have to set the `mat-sort-header` property of the `mat-header-cell` equal to your nested property string (see the demo for clarification).

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d5x6kg)

Comment: Your answer works perfectly. I just had to make a small correction. `getPropertyByPath(data.value, sortHeaderId)` => `getPropertyByPath(data, sortHeaderId)`