# How to hide ionic tags in angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Sorry if this is a basic question but I can't seem to figure it out.

Basically, I want to hide/show ionic tags when i tapped on button,I tried my level best to find solution to my problem but no result can some one help me please

### note.html:-

```
<ion-content padding>
  <div>
      <h1>No contacts available...</h1>
  </div>
<ion-content>
```

### notes.ts:

```
export class NotesPage {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

  }

hideContent(){

**I want hide that ionic tag when i call this method** 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a flag property in the component

```
showContent = true;

hideContent(){
  this.showContent = false;
}
```

And then use *ngIf

```
<ion-content padding *ngIf="showContent">
  <div>
      <h1>No contacts available...</h1>
  </div>
<ion-content>
```

You can also use the hidden property from html

```
<ion-content padding [hidden]="!showContent">
  <div>
      <h1>No contacts available...</h1>
  </div>
<ion-content>
```

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43034758/what-is-the-difference-between-ngif-and-hidden) to know about the differences between the 2 approaches.
Note that you can use these to hide/show any element in the template, not only 'ionic tag'.