# Angular 6 prevent [hidden] from blinking on page load

Tags: angular

I am trying to conditionally hide form validation items with the `[hidden]` attribute. It works but it blinks on page load even though I added `model.pristine` to the form.

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" [hidden]="model.valid || model.pristine">
   The model is required.
</div>
```

Comment: What's wrong with *ngIf? Where is your complete minimal example reproducing the issue?

Comment: If you're using angular, may aswell just change `[hidden]` to `*ngIf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `*ngIf` structural directive instead of using the `[hidden]` attribute.

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="!(model.valid || model.pristine)">
  The model is required.
</div>
```

You can read more about `*ngIf` vs. `[hidden]` [here](https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/difference-between-ngif-and-hidden-or-displaynone-in-angular/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43034758/what-is-the-difference-between-ngif-and-hidden/43034841).

Comment: Thanks, I think in this case it should be *ngIf="!model.valid && !model.pristine"

Comment: Good call, I forgot the flip the expression. Fixed that.