# Embedded view not showing when switching between views using ngIf

Tags: angular6

My component `A` has a child component `B`. On start up, `A` shows up because of conditition in `*ngIf`. `A` uses an `EmbeddedView` show show image thumbnails. `A` also has a button which when clicked changes the condition of `*ngIf` and shows `B` (because `B` shows on some other condition of `*ngIf`). If a button in `B` is pressed then `A` shows back again.

`A`'s html is something like

```
    <div *ngIf="this.tabType == this.questionTab" id="form-div-question" class="body__div--background"> 
    ....
    <ng-template #thumbnailTemplate let-context="context"> 
      <div id="{{context.divId}}"> 
        <button id="{{context.buttonId}}" type="button" data-toggle="modal" (click)="showEnlargeImage(context)">
          <img id="{{context.imgId}}" src="{{context.imgSrc}}"/> 
        </button>
        <a *ngIf="this.isEditing" href="javascript:void(0)" id="{{context.closeId}}" (click)="deleteThumbnailFromContainer(context)"></a> 
      </div>
    </ng-template>
...
  <div id="image-thumbnail-container">
    <ng-container #thumbnailContainer ></ng-container>
  </div>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="this.tabType == this.submittedAnswerTab" id="form-div-submitted-answer" class="body__div--background">
      <b-component #bComponent [someInput]="..." (someEventFromB)="switchToQuestionTab($event)"></b-component>
    </div>
```

The `EmbeddedView` in `A` is access as follows

```
  @ViewChild("thumbnailContainer",{read:ViewContainerRef})
  thumbnailContainerRef:ViewContainerRef;
```

What I am noticing is that on start up `A` shows fine including its embedded view. Then `B` also shows when the button in `A` is clicked. But when the view switches back to `A` then the embedded view doesn't show up!! (rest of `A` shows up correctly). I tried to force recreating the embedded view, I get error that the reference to the container is not defined (i.e.`thumbnailContainerRef` is `undefined`).

I also notice that when `B` is shown, it seem to be initiated everytime but when `A` is shown, it is not reinitialised everytime (maybe because `B` is child and `A` is parent)

Why is the container reference becoming `undefined`?

Answer (score 0):

Taking inspiration from [Angular 2 Show and Hide an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35163009/angular-2-show-and-hide-an-element) and [What is the difference between *ngIf and [hidden]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43034758/what-is-the-difference-between-ngif-and-hidden)

I seem to have solved the problem by using `[hidden]` instead of `ngIf` of `A` component.

```
<div [hidden]= "this.tabType != this.questionTab" ...>
</div>
<div *ngIf="this.tabType == this.submittedAnswerTab" id="form-div-submitted-answer" class="body__div--background">
      <b-component #bComponent [someInput]="..." (someEventFromB)="switchToQuestionTab($event)"></b-component>
    </div>
```

It seems that when '*ngIf' is false for `A`, Angular removes the embedded view and it doesn't get created again which seem to to be the reason why the `ViewContainerRef` is `undefined` when I switch back to `A`. Using `[hidden]` just hides `A`. Maybe there is code smell in my implementation but hey, I am still learning!