# Angular child component reloading everything placed inside ngif div

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-components

Here is code

```
<div *ngIf="active"><app-p-detail></app-p-detail></div>
```

Whenever I do `active = false` and again `true`. It reloads whole 'app-p-detail' component, means all services inside component, I do not want that. I just want to show the component data once load it completely and show/hide. Is this ngIf and component behavior normal or Am I doing something wrong? I am using Angular 11.

Comment: Use `hidden` ->  `<div [hidden]="variable">...</div>`

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I have a problem with [hidden] but why not '*ngIf' ? Can you please explain? Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43034758/what-is-the-difference-between-ngif-and-hidden

Comment: `*ngIf` removes element from DOM when `false` and re-render it when it's `true`. So, in your case,  as @Anurag Srivastava mentioned above,  you must hide it instead of removing it from DOM.

Comment: Yes that's how `*ngIf` works. Angular generates the DOM, and re-generates it when the data changes. if `*ngIf` is false, whatever's inside won't be rendered on the next pass. If you only want to hide it from view, use CSS.

Comment: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43034758/what-is-the-difference-between-ngif-and-hidden#:~:text=There%20is%20actually%20a%20performance,if%20the%20expression%20is%20false.&text=%5Bhidden%5D%20will%20load%20the%20data,if%20they%20are%20not%20visible.