# how to not validate hidden field in ng-click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

when user click on submit button i am validating form, using ng-click i am calling function, in this function i am passing form1.$invalid,based on this variable , i am putting condition, if condition true, validate function will call, here problem is mobile is hidden field, this hidden field also checking validation.how can skip or not validate mobile field hidden status,   I tried bellow code.

html
    ----

```
 <form name="form1" novalidate>
     <input ng-show="user" type="text" name="user" ng-model="frm1.user" />
    <p ng-show="form1.user.$error.required"><span ng-show="errorMsgShow" ng-required="true">{{requiredMsg}}</span></p>
     <input ng-show="mobile" type="text"  name="mobile" ng-model="frm1.mobile" />
    <p ng-show="form1.mobile.$error.required"><span ng-show="errorMsgShow" ng-required="true">{{requiredMsg}}</span></p>
    <button ng-click="SubmitForm(regForm.$invalid);">submit</button>
 </form>
```

Script----

```
$scope.SubmitForm = function(val){

$scope.user= true;
$scope.mobile = false;
 if (if(val ===true){
            $scope.validation();
  }
}
$scope.validation = function(){
  $scope.requiredMsg="input fieldis required";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest better approach will be taking the mobile input out of the form when it's unnecessary using **ng-if** rather than just hide it with **ng-show**.

**Ng-if** will make sure the input is not rendered in the DOM tree when the condition is false, therefore, there will be no validation triggered.

You can do some research on differences between ng-if and ng-show to have better understanding about these two directives.

Comment: how can i do that ,please help me

Comment: mobile field will show only user selected particular countries like ' US, UK, India' other wise it will hide.

Comment: @ramesh1226 use ng-if="mobile" and ng-if="user" in place of ng-show

Answer (score 0):

Try ng-if to avoid validation.If you want mobile to skip validation then make ng-if as false using expression.

syntax: ng-if="expression"

go to this link for further info

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

for difference between ng-if and ng-hide/ng-show refer the below link

[what is the difference between ng-if and ng-show/ng-hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177732/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-if-and-ng-show-ng-hide)

Comment: now i understand  very well but ,  it tried ng-if also but till it is not working

Comment: add a JSFiddle so i can check from my end

Answer (score 0):

**Some observations :**

- Instead of using `ng-show` to hide and show the inputs just use `<input type="hidden"... >` element for `mobile` field.
- No need to use variable `$scope.user` and `$scope.mobile` to hide and show the inputs.
- Add the `required` attribute in the `user` input field not on `mobile` input field as you don't want to validate mobile `field`.
- Use `SubmitForm(form1.$invalid)` instead of `SubmitForm(regForm.$invalid)` as your form name is `form1` not `regForm`.

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.SubmitForm = function(val) {
       console.log(val);
        if(val === true) {
            $scope.validation();
        }
    }
$scope.validation = function() {
  $scope.requiredMsg="input fieldis required";
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <form name="form1" novalidate>
     <input type="text" name="user" ng-model="frm1.user" required/>
    <p ng-show="form1.user.$error.required">{{requiredMsg}}</p>
     <input type="hidden" name="mobile" ng-model="frm1.mobile" />
    <button ng-click="SubmitForm(form1.$invalid);">submit</button>
 </form>
</div>
```