# I want the table to have hidden input fields which appear only when I click on them

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

My table has text input fields, which should be hidden when the page load and appear when I click on them. This is what I have tried and it isn't working. But the reverse is working, i can make the field disappear when i click on it.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <table id="sampleGrid" class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Fat (Z10006)</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" class="col-xs-8" name="Fat" ng-if="visible" ng-click="hidden()"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>    
    </table>
</div>
```

```
  var sampleApp =angular.module('sampleApp',[]);
  sampleApp.controller('gridController',function($scope,$http) {
     $scope.visible = false;
     $scope.hidden = function () {
        $scope.visible = true;
     };
  })
```

Comment: How can you click on an input field which is hidden? :-)

Comment: So is there anyway to implement this functionality, that i want the field to appear only when i intend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A small change was to be made. ng-click should be inside the  so that the cell would appear on click.

```
<td ng-click="hidden()"><input type="text" class="col-xs-8" name="Fat" ng-if="visible"></td>
```

Answer (score 2):

try `ng-show` instead of `ng-if`

```
<input type="text" class="col-xs-8" name="Fat" ng-show="visible" ng-click="hidden()">
```

Comment: A little bit of [extra information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177732/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-if-and-ng-show-ng-hide) on why this should be the correct answer. TL;DR when you use `ng-if` there is no longer that element in the DOM whereas `ng-show` is the same as setting the `display: none;`

Comment: @ramana I have tried ng-show as well. It is not working. when I click on the particular <td> nothing happens.

Comment: If it's the <td> that is clickable, you should put the angular logic on the <td>.

Comment: Yes cjs1978. It worked. ng-if on the input field and ng-click on the <td> . thanks