# ng-show/ng-hide doesn't work with lazy load of controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oclazyload

I am loading a state with ocLazyLoad. The controller of that state has this code in the start.

```
$scope.test = {show: false};
```

and in html view I have this

```
<button class="btn" ng-show="test.show">Hey There</button>
```

Now when my view is loaded the button is not hidden.
if I log {{test.show"}} it shows false. But this is not applying to button.

I tried something like this to execute controller when view is loaded

```
 $scope.$watch('$viewContentLoaded',
            function() {
                $timeout(function() {

                 },0);
            });
```

but nothing is working.

while `ng-show/ng-hide` is not working ng-if works perfectly. I am not able to understand why ng-show doesn't work and `ng-if` works. I need to use `ng-show/ng-hide`

Comment: Can u brief it with coding or make it in fiddle to analyze?

Comment: ng-if works perfectly because it adds and removes DOM element dynamicaaly. And DOM is re-compiled in this process. But ng-show/hide just set the dispaly property none and Dom is not recompiled.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177732/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-if-and-ng-show-ng-hide

Comment: Can you provide a plunkr ?

Comment: @Ved are you suggesting I should recompile my HTML if I want to use ng-hide/ng-show and if I do where should be I doing that?

Comment: No . I am not saying that. I am saying the limitation. Why not you are using ng-if

Comment: Because with ng-if  HTML will be recompiled creating child scope in elements wrapped inside ng-if. I don't want that. I have already written code and after so much development I decided to go for lazy loading. I am not sure that replacing ng-show with ng-if every where in my code will be good idea.

Answer (score -1):

Try it.

`<button class="btn" ng-hide="!test.show">Hey There</button>`

Comment: This doesn't work and it does not make any sense also as it is almost same thing as straight using ng-show.