# AngularJS ng-if and DOM Compilation

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if

I am using a datepicker control on my page which is rendered through ng-if dependent on a specific dropdown value.

The problem I'm facing is since at the time of rendering, that datepicker input is not part of DOM, so later when I change the value of dropdown, the datepicker control does not work.

If I use ng-show, I encounter issues in validations.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Which datepicker do you use or is it selfmade? And did you try to use the ControllerAs Syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use `ng-show/ng-hide` instead of `ng-if`,** because the `ng-if` directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree based on an expression. If the expression assigned to `ng-if` evaluates to a false value then the element is removed from the DOM, otherwise a clone of the element is reinserted into the DOM.

More details. please refer this link : [what is the difference between ng-if and ng-show/ng-hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177732/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-if-and-ng-show-ng-hide)

Comment: In case of ng-show/hide, I have to manually handle validations, right?

Comment: @AliHassan   Nope. `ng-show` also worksas `ng-if`. You just put the  expression which is you mentioned in `ng-if` expression.

Comment: Thanks Ramesh, let me have a look at it.

Comment: Worth adding is that ng-if also creates a new scope which can have it's downsides.

Comment: @AliHassan `ng-show` doesn't work as `ng-if`. The main difference is that the first one just uses css `display:none` to hide element whereas the second one removes element from DOM. It means that ng-show will keep validation errors becacuse ngModelController is still available. Could you please recreate your code at plnkr?

Answer (score 0):

Try "$scope.apply()" after the toggling of ng-if variable.