# Unable to retrieve dropdown ng-model value using ng-if, in Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 3 `dropdowns`.Dropdown first will control, out of `Dropdown 2` & `Dropdown 3` which dropdown to populate.

I am doing this using `ng-if`, I am able to use `ng-if` with the second dropdown, but when I unable to use `ng-if` with the third dropdown.
Reason I figured out is, `dropdown 2` is not binding any value with it.
I don't know why this is happening.
**code**

```
<select ng-model="selcetedValue">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="D">D</option>
</select>
<select ng-model="selcetedValueSecond" ng-if="selcetedValue === 'B'">
  <option value="E">E</option>
  <option value="F">F</option>
  <option value="G">G</option>
  <option value="H">H</option>
</select>
<select ng-model="selcetedValueThird" ng-if="selcetedValueSecond === 'H'">
  <option value="I">I</option>
  <option value="J">J</option>
  <option value="K">K</option>
  <option value="L">L</option>
</select>

<p>Selected value from first dropdown:: <i>{{selcetedValue}}</i></p>
<p>Selected value from second dropdown:: <i>{{selcetedValueSecond}}</i></p>
```

Please help.

Comment: `ng-show` will only hide the control from the page, but `ng-if`will remove the component from the DOM. I want to remove component if it is not required.

Comment: Here is the working one: https://jsfiddle.net/8wtvd46q/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ngIf` creates its own scope, You should define an object in `$scope` then use that to bind `ngModel` with select elements.

```
$scope.selectValues ={};
```

Then use it in view

```
<select ng-model="selectValues.selcetedValue">
</select>
<select ng-model="selectValues.selcetedValueSecond" ng-if="selectValues.selcetedValue === 'B'">
</select>
<select ng-model="selectValues.selcetedValueThird" ng-if="selectValues.selcetedValueSecond === 'H'">
</select>
```

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $filter, $sce) {
  $scope.selectValues = {};
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <select ng-model="selectValues.selcetedValue">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="D">D</option>
</select>
  <select ng-model="selectValues.selcetedValueSecond" ng-if="selectValues.selcetedValue === 'B'">
  <option value="E">E</option>
  <option value="F">F</option>
  <option value="G">G</option>
  <option value="H">H</option>
</select>
  <select ng-model="selectValues.selcetedValueThird" ng-if="selectValues.selcetedValueSecond === 'H'">
  <option value="I">I</option>
  <option value="J">J</option>
  <option value="K">K</option>
  <option value="L">L</option>
</select>

  <p>Selected values <i>{{selectValues}}</i></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

`ng-if` will create its own child scope. So your `ng-model` values are not directly binded to the controllers scope. You can use controller as syntax to avoid it. Other solution is to bind your `ng-model` to an object. controller as syntax is more preferred as it  will implicitly take care of the Dot Rule.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
 app.controller("myCtrl", function() {
   var vm =this;
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
<select ng-model="vm.selcetedValue">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="D">D</option>
</select>
<select ng-model="vm.selcetedValueSecond" ng-if="vm.selcetedValue === 'B'">
  <option value="E">E</option>
  <option value="F">F</option>
  <option value="G">G</option>
  <option value="H">H</option>
</select>
<select ng-model="vm.selcetedValueThird" ng-if="vm.selcetedValueSecond === 'H'">
  <option value="I">I</option>
  <option value="J">J</option>
  <option value="K">K</option>
  <option value="L">L</option>
</select>

<p>Selected value from first dropdown:: <i>{{vm.selcetedValue}}</i></p>
<p>Selected value from second dropdown:: <i>{{vm.selcetedValueSecond}}</i></p>
<p>Selected value from third dropdown:: <i>{{vm.selcetedValueThird}}</i></p>
</body>
</html>
```

**For more Info**: [What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 4):

You should use controller as syntax:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myctrl as $ctrl">
<select ng-model="$ctrl.selcetedValue">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="D">D</option>
</select>
<select ng-model="$ctrl.selcetedValueSecond" ng-if="$ctrl.selcetedValue === 'B'">
  <option value="E">E</option>
  <option value="F">F</option>
  <option value="G">G</option>
  <option value="H">H</option>
</select>
<select ng-model="$ctrl.selcetedValueThird" ng-if="$ctrl.selcetedValueSecond === 'H'">
  <option value="I">I</option>
  <option value="J">J</option>
  <option value="K">K</option>
  <option value="L">L</option>
</select>

<p>Selected value from first dropdown:: <i>{{$ctrl.selcetedValue}}</i></p>
<p>Selected value from second dropdown:: <i>{{$ctrl.selcetedValueSecond}}</i></p>

</div>
</div>
<script>
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('myctrl',function(){
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should always bind your model with dot.

Comment: https://thinkster.io/egghead/the-dot  Check this link. Upvote if helpful..

Comment: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/14/nested-scopes-in-angularjs.html or you can see this link. Much helpful..

Comment: So, my problem was, I was not using `Dot`, that's why I couldn't get the selected value of `Dropdown 2`, because it is referring to new space, instead of pointing to parent.

Comment: I didnot understand this line `<div ng-controller="myctrl as $ctrl">`

Comment: advantage is that it allows you to define your controllers as a simple javascript constructor function with properties and functions exposed directly from the instantiated object rather than the $scope. Please mark correct if it solved your problem. Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

> You should use `ng-show/hide` instead of `ng-if`, because of your **second** dropdown DOM is not in the current `scope` if you using `ng-if`. So the third dropdown `ng-if` does not knows which scope value is assigned in there expression.

### ngIf

The ngIf directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree based on an expression. If the expression assigned to ngIf evaluates to a false value then the element is removed from the DOM, otherwise a clone of the element is reinserted into the DOM.
 Read this discussion for more details;  [what is the difference between ng-if and ng-show/ng-hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177732/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-if-and-ng-show-ng-hide)

```js
angular.module("aaa",[]).controller("ccc",function($scope)
{
$scope.selcetedValue="";
$scope.selcetedValueSecond="";
$scope.selcetedValueThird="";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="aaa" ng-controller="ccc">

<select ng-model="selcetedValue">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="D">D</option>
</select>
<select ng-model="selcetedValueSecond" ng-show="selcetedValue === 'B'">
  <option value="E">E</option>
  <option value="F">F</option>
  <option value="G">G</option>
  <option value="H">H</option>
</select>
<select ng-model="selcetedValueThird" ng-show="selcetedValueSecond === 'H'">
  <option value="I">I</option>
  <option value="J">J</option>
  <option value="K">K</option>
  <option value="L">L</option>
</select>

<p>Selected value from first dropdown:: <i>{{selcetedValue}}</i></p>
<p>Selected value from second dropdown:: <i>{{selcetedValueSecond}}</i></p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-show/ng-hide instead

```
<select ng-model="selcetedValue">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="D">D</option>
</select>
<select ng-model="selcetedValueSecond" ng-show="selcetedValue === 'B'">
  <option value="E">E</option>
  <option value="F">F</option>
  <option value="G">G</option>
  <option value="H">H</option>
</select>
<select ng-model="selcetedValueThird" ng-show="selcetedValueSecond === 'H'">
  <option value="I">I</option>
  <option value="J">J</option>
  <option value="K">K</option>
  <option value="L">L</option>
</select>

<p>Selected value from first dropdown:: <i>{{selcetedValue}}</i></p>
<p>Selected value from second dropdown:: <i>{{selcetedValueSecond}}</i></p>
```

See this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/imraqes/1o7k20a6/1/)