# Why is selecting tab not working in PrimeNG?

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm trying to select `Tab2` by default, But it's not working correctly, It's selecting both tabs. I can see `Hello` and `World` on screen.

```
<p-tabView>
    <p-tabPanel header="Tab1">
        Hello
    </p-tabPanel>
    <p-tabPanel header="Tab2" [selected]="true">
        World
    </p-tabPanel>
</p-tabView>
```

I'm using primeng version 4.1.2.

Reference: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/tabview

Comment: can you check if all other attributes are working or is there any error in console. because i don't think this is an issue.

Comment: What do you mean by other attributes are working ? There is no error in console.

Comment: other attributes like [closable] or [disabled]

Comment: How will it help to solve my problem?

Comment: let's investigate the issue by checking if all other attributes are working for that same element if yes then there should be an issue with that element if no then there is some issue while importing this TabViewModule.

Comment: @HrishikeshKale other attributes are working perfectly fine

Comment: I don't have your problem with PrimeNG 4.1.2 : [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/QQPQPJ6GHlRVylHNdtva?p=preview)

Comment: @Antikhippe Yes, it's working fine. Then What could be the possible reason?

Comment: even I have tried using this but it works fine and as expected. will you try to install this primeng again or using their latest version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue, posting here so that it can help others.

I was using `*ngIf="someCondition"` with `<p-tabPanel header="Tab1">` tag, I have used `[hidden]="!someCondition"` eqivalent of `ng-hide="someCondition"` in AngularJS.

```
<p-tabView>
    <p-tabPanel header="Tab1">
        Hello
    </p-tabPanel>
    <p-tabPanel header="Tab2" [selected]="true" [hidden]="!someCondition">
        World
    </p-tabPanel>
</p-tabView>
```

The reason you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19177773/6527049).