# ng-show does not hide a button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show

I have a selector with more options, I want to hide a button if the first option of the selector is selected.

```html
<select ng-model="$ctrl.type">
    <option value="">none</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

as it can be seen, the first option has `value =""`.

This is the button:

```
    <div ng-show="$ctrl.type!=""" class="btn action-btn" ng-click="$ctrl.doSomething()">
        my button
    </div>
```

inside the controller I have this code:

```js
class MyCtrl {
  constructor(...) {
    ...
  }

  doSomething() {
    this.type = "";
  }
}
```

Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the main issue is that you are using the same double quotes when you should be using different ones.

```
<div ng-show="ctrl.type !== ''" class="btn action-btn" ng-click="$ctrl.doSomething()">
        my button
</div>
```

This being said I would use a Boolean flag for this, because it makes the code and the checks much easier to read and understand:

```
doSomething() {
    if ( type !== '' )
    this.showForType = true;
  }


<div ng-show="ctrl.showForType === true" class="btn action-btn" ng-click="$ctrl.doSomething()">
        my button
</div>
```

you don't necessarily need a check for true, but it does help from a maintenance and readability point of view.

The same could be done with something like:

```
<div ng-show="ctrl.showForType" class="btn action-btn" ng-click="$ctrl.doSomething()">
        my button
</div>
```

If any part of your angular controlled UI elements show while the right states are not set you can use ng-cloak to stop that from happening : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Comment: it seems pretty correct. I just observed that when the page loads for a little of time there is the button on the screen, maybe it does the check from ng-show later, I tried to use an ng-hide with the negated condition but still it stays on the screen at the beginning

Comment: added more to my answer to cover this issue as well

Answer (score 2):

It should be as,

```
<div ng-show="ctrl.type!=''" class="btn action-btn" ng-click="$ctrl.doSomething()">
```

Comment: don't you mean `ng-show="ctrl.type!=''"`? I think it is an extra `"` in yours but still does not work

Comment: @LeoMessi May be that's the typo issue from the answer-er. I have  changed .

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

```
<div ng-show="!ctrl.type" class="btn action-btn" ng-click="$ctrl.doSomething()">
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `ng-show` condition is incorrect as it is not checking the empty value. To make it work you need to change your code to,

```
<div ng-show="ctrl.type!=''" class="btn action-btn" ng- 
 click="$ctrl.doSomething()">
    my button
</div>
```

You can further enhance this to use `trim()` to get rid of whitespaces from `ctrl.type` and get proper result during comparison. For this you can use,

```
<div ng-show="ctrl.type.trim()!=''" class="btn action-btn" ng- 
 click="$ctrl.doSomething()">
    my button
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by these three ways

### one

> `ng-hide="$ctrl.type==''"`// correct way  and related naming functionality

### two

> `ng-show ="$ctrl.type!=''"`// correct way but unrelated naming for the functionality

### three

> `ng-if="$ctrl.type!=''"` // correct way without render the DOM elements

---

Kindly check : [what is the difference between ng-if and ng-show/ng-hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177732/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-if-and-ng-show-ng-hide)