# Combine ng-if with ng-click in angluarJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, angular-ng-if

There is a button which must show a toggle only if a value is greater than 0. Otherwise it shouldn't do anything.

This is the code before adding `ng-if`:

```
<span >{{values.valuesNumber}} 
      <i class="fas fa-caret-down" ng-click="$ctrl.doSomething(values)">
      </i>
</span>
```

I want to call the function from `ng-click` only when `values.valuesNumber > 0`.

So I added it like the following but it does not work.

```
 <span >{{values.valuesNumber}} <i class="fas fa-caret-down">
     <span ng-if="values.valuesNumber > 0">
         <span ng-click="$ctrl.doSomething(values)">
         </span>
     </span>
 </i></span>
```

Comment: try `ng-click="$parent.$ctrl.doSomething(values)"`

Comment: Did you forget to add $ctrl to values? like here: $ctrl.ng-if="values.valuesNumber > 0"

Comment: Can you post more code? The declaration of your `controller` would help.

Comment: What do you mean by it does not work?. You should explain the problem clearly.

Answer (score 0):

use `ng-show` instead of `ng-if`. Because `ng-if` creates a scope of it's own.

```
<span >{{values.valuesNumber}} <i class="fas fa-caret-down">
     <span ng-show="values.valuesNumber > 0">
         <span ng-click="$ctrl.doSomething(values)">
         </span>
     </span>
 </i></span>
```

Also please take a look at this discussion:

[what is the difference between ng-if and ng-show/ng-hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177732/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-if-and-ng-show-ng-hide)

Comment: "Don't use _A_, use _B_" is not the best solution

Comment: Had you read this from the link which is providing in my answer? **When an element is removed using ngIf its scope is destroyed and a new scope is created when the element is restored. The scope created within ngIf inherits from its parent scope using prototypal inheritance.** . This is thr problem with `ngIf`. So the solution is `ng-show/hide`

Comment: you can also reach parent's scope with `$parent`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Yeah! that's also a better way to solve this. I am just answered it for an another option. Because I saw your comments and you have mentioned there. So i don't want to answer that. :)

Comment: **"Don't use A, use B"** . If A does not working, then  there have no problem for go with B.