# toggling "ng-hide" property with condition on button click

Tags: angularjs

```
<input ng-model="email" type="text" class="marginHalf" ng-hide="email==''" readonly>
```

When on edit button click, Show this so user ca add an email.

Comment: I guess what you need is `ngReadonly`. Check [HERE](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.32/docs/api/ng/directive/ngReadonly) please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a flag in your controller to toggle on and off when your edit button is clicked.

```
$scope.editMode = false;
$scope.onEditButtonClick = function(){
    $scope.editMode = true;
}
```

then you use a condition that checks this variable but I recommend using ng-if instead.

```
<input ng-model="email" type="text" class="marginHalf" ng-if="editMode" readonly>
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177732/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-if-and-ng-show-ng-hide) is the difference between ng-if and ng-show/ng-hide.