# Ng-If only working when refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ng-if, ng-show

I have a problem with ng-if, I am pretty new to angularjs. I want to show/hide a searchbar only on certain views, but it only works after refreshing the page. But it should work, when the view changed.

html:

```
<div id="searchbarTop" ng-controller="searchbarController">
  <form class="col-md-12 py-1" ng-if="!showSearchbarTop">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control typeahead" id="query" 
        placeholder="Search for folders or workflows..." data- 
        provide="typeahead" autocomplete="off" ng-wflist="workflowList" wf-search/>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

controller:

```
ProjectX.controller("searchbarController", function($scope,$http,$location) {
    $scope.$root.showSearchbarTop = $location.path() === "/";

       ...
});
```

Hope someone can explain me, which mistake I made.

Comment: That's how it's. You could try using class to show and hide.

Comment: You can try and change `ng-if` with `ng-show`, but be aware that there are differences https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177732/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-if-and-ng-show-ng-hide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `showSearchbarTop` as an attribute which is initialized only at the beginning of the page load. That's why, you need to use it as a function.

See the following code

```js
var ProjectX = angular.module('', []);
ProjectX.controller("searchbarController", function($scope, $http, $location) {
  $scope.$root.showSearchbarTop = function() {
    return $location.path() === "/";
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="searchbarTop" ng-controller="searchbarController">
  <form class="col-md-12 py-1" ng-if="!showSearchbarTop()">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control typeahead" id="query" placeholder="Search for folders or workflows..." data- provide="typeahead" autocomplete="off" ng-wflist="workflowList" wf-search/>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```