# How to filter Multidimensional Array with limitTo in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, multidimensional-array, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter, angularjs-limitto

I have a following Multidimensional Array in the controller.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('myController',function($scope){
   $scope.myData = [{name:'Person1',surname:'Surname1'},
                    {name:'Person2',surname:'Surname1'},
                    {name:'Person3',surname:'Surname2'},
                    {name:'Person4',surname:'Surname3'},
                    {name:'Person5',surname:'Surname3'}];
});
```

I've tried following code to use `limitTo` and `filter` with `ng-repeat` to filter and limit the display of elements.

```
<div ng-if="myData.length !== 0"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter name to search" ng-model="mySearch"/></div>
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>Surname</th>
  <tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="tr in myData | filter:{name:mySearch} | limitTo: 1:2">
   <td ng-bind="tr.name" ng-cloak></td>
   <td ng-bind="tr.surname" ng-cloak></td>
  <tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

But from the above piece of code I'm only able to limit the records but not able to filter based on the input.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the second value you have added to your LimitTo filter. As it is written in the documentation

```
{{ limitTo_expression | limitTo : limit : begin}}
```

second value sets the index at which to begin limitation. If you remove 2 from your limitTo your code should work the way you want.

```
  <tr ng-repeat="tr in myData | filter:{name:mySearch} | limitTo: 1">
   <td ng-bind="tr.name" ng-cloak></td>
   <td ng-bind="tr.surname" ng-cloak></td>
  <tr>
```

**[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/Fhb348VzEldHFAyp0um0?p=preview)**

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, but not able to filter using keywords. I'm using AngularJS v1.6.9

Comment: @BBRK check the plunker demo please. Enter Person2 in the input and see how result changes.

Comment: Yes I saw the demo and it's working as expected, not sure why it's not working at my end.

Comment: @BBRK there is a typo in your input, notice the m in your input.

Comment: I have just updated my question, can you check if this may be causing the issue.

Comment: @BBRK No, I do not think that line would cause the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `ng-if` was causing the issue. I replaced `ng-if` with `ng-show` and it worked.

I found the explanation regarding the difference between the two in the following post.

[What is the difference between ng-if and ng-show/ng-hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177732/what-is-the-difference-between-ng-if-and-ng-show-ng-hide)

Code after changes:-

```
<div ng-show="myData.length !== 0"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter name to search" ng-model="mySearch"/></div>
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>Surname</th>
  <tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="tr in myData | filter:{name:mySearch} | limitTo: 1:2">
   <td ng-bind="tr.name" ng-cloak></td>
   <td ng-bind="tr.surname" ng-cloak></td>
  <tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this helps someone.