# Can't bind to 'showQR' since it isn't a known property of 'div'?

Tags: angular

I have a div that looks like this

```
 <div
    class="empower-btn"
    [showQR]="showQR"
    [selectedCoin]="coin"
    [availableAmount]="getCoinAmount()"
    [coinAmount]="getCoinAmount()"
  >stuff</div>
```

And in my component
i declared the properties like this

```
 showQr;
 coinAmount;
 coin;
 availableAmount;
```

however i am getting an error of

> Can't bind to 'showQR' since it isn't a known property of 'div'?

how can i remove this error?
thanks
am i binding the property in a wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the basic understanding of using a custom attribute  in DOM. We use directives for this. AngularJS has few built in attribute directives like ng-model, ng-class etc. Don't get confused by them. Just because things are abstracted from you doesn't mean it is not implemented.

Please refer to the documentation to understand the concept of directives in detail. [Directive AngularJS Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Answer (score 1):

Please replace [showQR] with `*ng-if` or `ng-show`. `ng-if` will delete and recreate the `div` each time showQR changes. `ng-Show` will keep the `div` there, but simply hide and show the `div`. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/19177773/16607579)

Also, you should not add the other variables in this way. Instead can use `ng-bind`: https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-bind.asp

(May need to create a separate html element for each variable)