# Why is my AngularJS textarea not binding to my variable?

Tags: angularjs

My HTML is as follows:

```
<textarea ng-model="cancelMessage"></textarea>
<span {{100 - cancelMessage.length}} characters remaining</span>
```

In my controller I declare a variable as follows:

```
$scope.cancelMessage = '';
```

When I type in the text area, the number of characters remaining actually updates. However, when I try to access

```
$scope.cancelMessage
```

(via ng-click), the variable is still '' and not the text in the text area.

Comment: Could be a scope issue, can you include the HTML that includes the ng-click?

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem and this solved the problem for me:

[Cannot get textarea value in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284442/cannot-get-textarea-value-in-angularjs)

Basically Angular created a new scope. Use $parent.cancelMessage in your textarea ng-model attrbibute instead.

Answer (score 2):

Created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cTqE8/) for the problem. Hope you get an idea where you making the mistake.

Here is the controller function:

```
function test($scope){
    $scope.cancelMessage = '';
    $scope.clickTest = function(){
        alert($scope.cancelMessage);
    }
}
```