# Update text area when scope is changed

Tags: angularjs, arrays, scope, angularjs-scope, angular-nglist

So I have a text area defined with an ng-list that will separate the elements in an array into their own line.

```
  <textarea data-ng-model="names" data-ng-list="&#10;" data-ng-trim="false"></textarea>
```

I have a button that will add things to the names array and I want it to show up in the textarea as well.

```
<button data-ng-click='addPlayer()'>Add</button>

$scope.addPlayer = function() {
  $scope.names.push('HODOR' + n++);
}
```

Unfortunately the textarea will not update when more elements are added to the array, even if they are still stored in the array.  Is their anyway I can force that to happen?  I tried using $scope.$apply and that didnt work.  Here is a plunker showing the error.  https://plnkr.co/edit/gaLtvWw3Odhfngrhkitf?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at this:

[Cannot get textarea value in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284442/cannot-get-textarea-value-in-angularjs)

Using $scope.$apply wont work, the textarea is a directive and:

> AngularJS will look for that variable in the scope of the directive. It is not there and thus he walks down to $parent. The variable is present there and the text is inserted into the textarea. When changing the text in the textarea, Angular does NOT change the parent's variable. Instead it creates a new variable in the directive's scope and thus the original variable is not updated.

Comment: So if I am understanding this correctly, I should change data-ng-model="names" to data-ng-model="$parent.names", but doing so just completely disconnects the textarea from the array.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: @IFM use controllerAs :

controller: "MyController",
controllerAs: "myc",

Then set the value in your controller:

angular.module('myApp').controller('MyController', function () {
    this.myText = 'Dummy text';
});

And then bind it directly to the property of your controller using the controller as identifier:

<textarea ng-model="myc.myText"></textarea>