# Angular ng-model not binding to textarea

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working with Angular 1.5 and am having trouble getting my textarea to bind to the model and access it in the controller.

In my controller I am initializing a variable :

```
$scope.textModel = "";
```

and in my template I have :

```
<textarea ng-model="textModel"></textarea>
```

If I put in my template :

```
<div>{{textModel}}</div>
```

under the textarea I can see what is being typed. However in a function that gets called on button click I cannot see the value of $scope.textModel

```
$scope.onButtonClick = function() {
  var x = $scope.textModel; // gets assigned as ""  
}
```

Not sure what I'm missing here....

Sample code

```
export default (TestService) => {
     return TestService.show({
        template: (() => { 
            let modalHeader = `
            <modal-header-content>
                <div ng-if="!editing">
                    <textarea ng-model="textInput" placeholder="Add "></textarea>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-accent" ng-click="methods.addObj()">Add</button>
                </div>
            </modal-header-content>
            `;
            return [
                '<modal-template>',
                modalHeader,
                '</modal-template>'
            ].join('');
        })(),
        controller: ($scope) => {

            $scope.textInput = "";
            $scope.testArray = [];

            $scope.methods = {
                addObj: () => {
                    let newObj = {};
                    newTribute.message = $scope.textInput; //getting set as ""
                    $scope.testArray.push(newObj);
                    $scope.textInput = '';
                }
            }
        }
     })
}
```

Comment: Is the button in the exact same scope as the text-area?

Comment: @Phil Yes the button is right under the textarea in the template

Comment: And the `$scope.onButtonClick` function is in the exact same controller as `$scope.textModel = ""`? Instead of little code snippets, it would be great if you could put everything in context

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284442/cannot-get-textarea-value-in-angularjs  In the textarea, put `<textarea ng-model="$scope.textModel"></textarea>`

Comment: @Marc good link but that code doesn't look right

Comment: @Phil sample code is updated