# Textarea is not working with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, inspinia

Am new to Angular JS. Am working on messaging. Am stuck with this point.
I have following ng-repeat structure.

```
<div ng-repeat="x in MessageUserList | filter:curPlace">  
  <textarea class="form-control" id="message" ng-model="user.message"></textarea>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary m-t-n-xs" 
  ng-click="SendMessage(myData.member_id,x.member.member_id);">Send message           
  </button>
</div>
```

[image: .]

MessageUserList JSON data is:

[{
  "member":{"member_id":23,
  "first_name":"Suyash",
  "middle_name":"Jamesh",
  "last_name":"Jamesh",
  "joining_date":"02-06-2017",
  "phone":7411556977
 so on....
}]

User photo and name is coming dynamically from web service
Am passing myData.member_id and x.member.member_id as parameter when I click on Send Message button. Now at the same time I want to pass text area value also to a  controller. I used deep copy. But it is not working.

My controller is:

```
$scope.SendMessage = function(user_id,to_whom_sen_id) { 
   $scope.user_id = user_id;
   $scope.to_whom_sen_id = to_whom_sen_id;
   var r = angular.copy(user, $scope.message);
   alert(r); //Not working
};
```

Comment: Where is MessageUserList?

Comment: Please provide a complete example.

Comment: Now I edited my question...

Answer (score 0):

ng-model for your textarea is user.message, then in angular.copy it should be

```
var r = angular.copy($scope.user.message);
```

hope it would help.

Comment: Actually in my case I have text boxes of same ng-model name thats why not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="message" ng-model="message"></textarea>
```

Comment: `var r = angular.copy(user, $scope.message);` where does `user` var come from?

Comment: This might relate to scope issue, try answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284442)